# Where is the legend for graduated styling?

Tags: qgis, style, legend

I created a map using graduated styling on a layer and there is a field for legend format and a column that says legend, but I can't find the legend anywhere.
Does anyone know how to access it?
(The only thing in the legends tab within the layer properties window is something that says transparency slider)?
Ideally I would like to save it as a png.
[image]

Comment: The legend will be a part of your map you create in the print composer. In print composer, you add a new map first then add a legend as a new map item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access you legend you must create the **Print Composer**, for more information about it you can read [here](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/making_a_map.html).

What do you have to do is: Start Qgis (open your project) > Project > New Print Composer> "Composer title" > Layout > Add map > Layout > Add legend...